# Launch an external app from an App

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am creating an android APP using Ionic framework,I want to launch an external app from my app.

I included the acces-orgin in the config.xml

```
<access origin="speedtest:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

I am using the following code

```
<button class="button button-positive" ng-click="btnClick()"> Launch Speed Test</button>
```

In My app.js

```
 function onDeviceReady() {

        var scheme;

        // Don't forget to add the org.apache.cordova.device plugin!
        if(device.platform === 'iOS') {
            scheme = 'speedtest://';
        }
        else if(device.platform === 'Android') {

            scheme = 'org.zwanoo.android.speedtest';
        }
        $scope.btnClick = function() {
            appAvailability.check(
            scheme, // URI Scheme
            function() {  // Success callback

                window.open('speedtest://', '_system', 'location=no');

                console.log('Speedtest is available');
            },
            function() {  // Error callback
            //alert("not available");
                window.open('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zwanoo.android.speedtest', '_system', 'location=no');
                console.log('Speedtest is not available');
            }
        );
        } 

    }
```

the following line is not working  and it does not throw any error in the console.

```
window.open('speedtest://', '_system', 'location=no');
```

Please guide me .

Comment: try whitelisting - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can start an external application using third party plugin. Please follow the link below

[Plugin for check or launch other application in android device](https://github.com/venkykowshik/startapp)

e.g.

Check application for installed

```
navigator.startApp.check("com.application.name", function(message) { /* success */
    console.log(message); // => OK
}, 
function(error) { /* error */
    console.log(error);
});
```

Start external application

```
navigator.startApp.start("com.application.name", function(message) {  /* success */
    console.log(message); // => OK
}, 
function(error) { /* error */
    console.log(error);
});
```